# How do I extract a number in decimal representation from a `&[u8]` and compare it with an integer?

Tags: rust

Here's an example of my code:

```
use bytes::Bytes;
use regex::bytes::Regex as BytesRegex;

fn main() {
    let val = b"2020-01-01";
    let my_regex = BytesRegex::new(r"\d{4}-(\d{2})-\d{2}").unwrap();
    let month = my_regex.captures(val).unwrap().get(1).unwrap();
    let month_digit = std::str::from_utf8(month.as_bytes()).unwrap().parse::<u8>().unwrap();
    println!("month smaller than 12: {}", month_digit<=12);
}
```

https://gist.github.com/rust-play/92d4e4855015317451abad775adceec1

Like this, I was able to print out the captured group as an unsigned integer. But, I had to go via `std::str::from_utf8`.

Is there a way to get the same result without converting to `str`?

Comment: not quite - I have `&[u8]`, not `&[u8; 4]`. Having an answer here might be helpful to others

Comment: `month.as_bytes().iter().fold (0, |acc, c| acc*10 + (c - '0' as u8))` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=79d8e5ce7aefe5212662a7413fd59de3))

Comment: Those answers are not restricted to `&[u8; 4]`, I think.

Comment: More importantly `[49]` should be interpreted as `1`, but the proposed duplicates would interpret it as `49`…

Comment: @mkrieger1 look at the code in the question: the byte slice is actually an ASCII string that the OP wants to parse. So `[49]`, which is `b"1"`, should be parsed as `1`.

Comment: you want parse a text based input but not as a text based input aka str ? that make no sense

Comment: why was this marked as duplicate? @Jmb's answer isn't in the duplicates, and is exactly what I needed. I'm so confused

Comment: @ignoring_gravity so it's a good thing both questions can now be discovered from each other no? It's asking the same thing, how to get from ascii bytes to a number.

Comment: @ignoring_gravity, we vote for duplicates based on the _question_, not the answers.

Comment: sure - I was just suggesting that if the answer is different, it suggests there might be something different about the question too. Anyway, thanks for explaining, and for all your help, much appreciated, and I'm sorry to have been a pain here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done easily with [`Iterator::fold`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.fold) and basic arithmetic:

```
let month_digit = month.as_bytes().iter().fold (0, |acc, c| acc*10 + (c - b'0'))
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=e4d338ac83053a50fbc586ddc4502013)